# c undefined reference to function - Compiling android/linux kernel

Tags: android, c, compiler-construction, linux-kernel

I am compiling the Android 2.6.35 kernel found on [OMAPZoom.org](http://omapzoom.org/) and I am stuck with what I think is a silly Makefile problem.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage
```

yields the following error (plus more that are related):

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `dsscomp_createcomp':
drivers/video/omap2/dsscomp/device.c:175: undefined reference to `tiler_set_buf_state'
```

drivers/video/omap2/dsscomp/device.c has the following #include directive:

```
#include <mach/tiler.h>
```

which I believe references the following file containing the prototype:

```
arch/arm/mach-omap2/include/mach/tiler.h
```

In turn, tiler_set_buf_state is defined in:

```
drivers/media/video/tiler/tiler.c
```

The function is being used correctly, the header is included. This leads me to think the definition is not being compiled.  This project is using a rather large recursive Makefile setup.

I'm not really sure what more I can put in here that will be helpful, but if there is something that would be useful ask me.  I was hoping that someone could give me a push in the right direction.

Comment: An undefined reference in a .o file tends to be due to a missing link dependency, not a missing include.  (Though a possible exception would be if a header file was actually supposed to provide the implementing code, but is instead merely providing a prototype)  You can check that a particular line in source is being compiled by putting a #error there and verifying that this halts the build, but the possibility that it is being compiled but not linked remains - you might want to look at the full command issued for that stage of the build.  You can also grep for the identifier in .o files.

Comment: That's a neat trick, I will have to stash that away for future use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing:

There are two (relevant) branches in that repository:

```
p-android-omap-2.6.35
p-android-omap3-2.6.35
```

The first one does not work with OMAP3, or at least with the Zoom3 (board config of android_zoom3_defoncifg).

To build the kernel for the Zoom3, you must use the second (p-android-omap3-2.6.35) branch or you will get tons of build errors.  Wasted most of a day re-writing "broken" code from the first branch thinking it was incorrect since I'm using an older board.  Did a checkout on the correct branch and it built without any errors.

Sorry. Hopefully this will be helpful for someone else!

Answer (score 1):

What does drivers/media/video/tiler/Kconfig say? Are you sure that all of CFLAGS are set correctly? I've built an android for the omap4 platform and had to pass in this variable in my makefile : "TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM=omap4". I haven't exactly traced where that goes.( My system too has a complicated Makefile). But you should probably make sure that 
ARCH_OMAP4 is set correctly somewhere in your makefile.

On my system Kconfig has:

```
config TILER_OMAP
    tristate "OMAP TILER support"
    default y
    depends on ARCH_OMAP4
help
       TILER driver for OMAP based boards.

config DUCATI_BUFFER_PROTECTION
    tristate "OMAP DUCATI input buffer protection"
    default y
    depends on TILER_OMAP
help
       Reserve 8MB memory for input buffer protection
```

Comment: My Kconfig has eaxctly the top portion as yours but stops before help.  Is this only for OMAP4?  I was under the impression this worked on OMAP3 as well. OMAP3 is my target.

Comment: OK This must be a custom setting with my kernel. Is -DARCH_OMAP4 set somewhere in your config/ Makefile?

Comment: Grep-ed my kernel folder.  "DARCH_OMAP4" is not in any file.

Comment: See my above answer. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: Well glad you figured it out!